# how to rotate text with css? transform is not supported by current schema?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, transform

So I am trying to rotate some text for use on a panel (slider) on a SharePoint web page.

```
.rot-text{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

not supported by the SPS2010 schema? is there a way to get the same thing with older method?

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Cross Browser CSS Transforms – even in IE](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)

Comment: If that does not work you could try jquery rotate > http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom CSS file and add it as a reference to the master page used to format your site.

Erik Swenson has a good overview of the parts of the CSS structure here:

[SharePoint 2010 CSS references in Master Pages](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-css-references-in.html)

Finally here is a page from Microsoft on how to use the Master Page to customize your site:

[Customize a master page to brand your site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-HA102449505.aspx)